# Error 500 on RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want the following behaviour:

```
http://www.example.com/mysubdir -> show /mysubdir/index.htm
http://www.example.com/mysubdir/first -> show /mysubdir/redirect.php?token=first
http://www.example.com/mysubdir/first/second -> show /mysubdir/redirect.php?token=first&action=second
http://www.example.com/mysubdir/first/second/third -> show /mysubdir/redirect.php?token=first&action=second&param=third
```

therefore I created the following .htaccess (inside mysubdir)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysubdir/
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/? ./redirect.php?token=$1&action=$2&param=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/? ./redirect.php?token=$1&action=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/? ./redirect.php?token=$1 [L]
```

This causes an error 500

If I remove the last line, however, the first two rules work as expected. I can't see any visible difference between these rules that should cause such an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting 500 (internal server error) because your rules are looping infinitely due to presence of `[^/]+` in your last rule that will match rewritten URI `redirect.php` also.

You can fix it using this modified code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysubdir/

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ redirect.php?token=$1&action=$2&param=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ redirect.php?token=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ redirect.php?token=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Few more changes made are:

1. Use `QSA` to preserve any existing query string in URLs.
2. You should use anchor `$` in your regex patterns.
3. No need to escape `/` in regex patterns.

Comment: not preserving any parameters is actually a wanted behavior.Thanks for solving this and the additional information

Comment: ok, in that case you can skip `QSA` flag for discarding query string sent with your pretty URLs.